# avoid non matching IDs

Tags: r

I am subsetting and ordering a dataframe according to an external vector which contains IDs non-matching the col name. How can I avoid the NAs in the final data.frame?

```
a<-c(2, 4, 6, 6, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14)
b<-c(21:29)
name<-c("O1", "O2", "O3", "O4", "O5","O6", "O7", "O8", "O9")
ID<-rep(c("no","bo", "fo"), each=3)
df<-data.frame(name,ID, a, b)

target<-c("O5","O6", "O7", "O3", "O4", "O1", "O2", "O10", "O11")
    newdf <- df[match(target, df$name),]

   name   ID  a  b
5    O5   bo  8 25
6    O6   bo 10 26
7    O7   fo 12 27
3    O3   no  6 23
4    O4   bo  6 24
1    O1   no  2 21
2    O2   no  4 22
NA   <NA> <NA> NA NA
NA.1 <NA> <NA> NA NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `nomatch=0` in the `match`.  By default, the non matching elements will be occupied by 'NA'.  When there is an `NA` element, it will add an additional `NA` row for each `NA` from the `match`.

```
df[match(target, df$name, nomatch=0),]
```

Or we can use `%in%` to get the logical index of elements in 'name' that are also in target and use that as row index.

```
df[df$name %in% target,]
```

Comment: How can I keep the target order with the second approach?

Comment: @Al14 If the order is important, you should use the `match`